# Run java application in the background

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, background, jpanel

I have a simple java application that popup a JPanel after a certain condition is met and I want to run this application once the user opens the PC ( once he login to his windows account). After I searched through the internet I realized that I can achieve this by creating a jar file for the application and then creating a batch file that runs this jar file but the problem now is I dont know where I supose to place the batch file in so it can be called automatically once the user login and if there is another easer way to automate the execution of the application rather than the .jar and .batch file ?

Comment: This is less a Java problem and more of a Windows-user problem since how this is done depends on the version of Windows run.

Comment: Press Winkey + R (for Start - Run dialog) and type `shell:startup`. This will open the users startup folder.

Comment: how can I open the RunOnce registry in windows 7 ?